# Object id or Object reference

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dapper

I am wondering if is it better to add a reference to an external object in my class or to add just its Id. I want to create those objects from database, using dapper or directly ADO.NET. So I want to know if there is a performance difference between the two approach.

for example I have the following object

```
Class Object1
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    string Name {get;set;}
    //... etc
}
```

and I have another object Object2 which have a reference to Object1

```
Class Object2
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    //is it better to add this
    Object1 object1 {get;set;}
    //or to add just an Id
    int objectId {get;set;}
}
```

Object2 may have other references to other objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick with a reference to the object, as it will reduce the amount of access code you have to write when using your object relational mapper. Like retrieving the object from the ID, as well as reducing the likely hood of making unnecessary repeat accesses.

However if you are storing a very large amount of these objects in memory and you don't always require access to the object reference, it may be more efficient to just keep the ID.

It's kind of a balancing act but in most cases object reference won't affect you. I would need more information on the use case.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, in `.NET framework` whatever type you use, is derived from the parent type `System.Object`. So whether you use `int, string, double` or any other `type`, is derived from System.Object. So, either case it is a reference to the object whether the object is `primitive` or not.

Now, from the `clean code` point of view, you should write separate objects whenever you can club the data together. If you see any probability of clubbing same sort of data, then go ahead and do it, because that is going to increase code readability. Many a times, you see a class with a lot of data members, and it is your logical ability to club them and make classes out of them.

Comment: By club, do you mean group?

Comment: @jrahhali Mark all the members with which you can create a class and make sense...

Comment: Not entirely sure how this addresses OP question of _"I am wondering if is it better to add a **reference** to an external object in my class or to add just its **Id**"_.